# Maintaining/accessing global state in Gatsby site

Tags: reactjs, jsx, gatsby

I am currently trying to implement a fairly simple feature in a Gatsby JS driven site, which was built by someone else and am facing the following problem:

The page currently darkens the background when a modal is opened, I would like to have the background blur instead though. In order to achieve the darker background, the component for the modal includes a div, with fixed position, which fills the window, the css of which is as follows:

```
.background_fader {
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

I have tried using `filter: blur(20px)` instead of the `background-color`, but to no avail. It appears, that even when I change the `z-index` of the div, I am not able to blur the background, but would rather have to add the `filter`  property at the wrapper of the page, i.e. much higher up in the hierarchy.

I have some experience with react and almost none with Gatsby, so please excuse if this question is simple/ rooted in a fundamental misconception. 
What I have dealt with so far, were pages which used Redux as a centralized state and the much wider question which arose in implementing the blurring is this:

**How do I add a state to the root-component of the Gatsby page in order to pass relevant aspects down to child components and thereby rerender the page?**

After doing some research, I came to the conclusion, that it should be possible to use the `wrapRootElement` function from gatsby-browser.js in order to define a state at the root of the app, but I am having trouble implementing this, because the only props I seem to be able to access in the "root" component, which is generated from layouts/index.js are the data retrieved  from Graphql.

Currently the layouts/index.js looks like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import graphql from 'graphql';
import Helmet from 'react-helmet';
import classNames from 'classnames';

// import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import './reset.css';
import '../components/styleguide/index.less';
import Feedback from '../components/feedback';
import Navbar from '../components/Nav';
import Footer from '../components/footer';
import Subscribe from '../components/Subscribe';
import './index.less';

export default ({
  children, location, data: {
    FooterSettings: { edges: [{ node: { frontmatter: footerData } }] },
    NavbarSettings: { edges: [{ node: { frontmatter: navbarSettings } }] },
    HomepageSettings: { edges: [{ node: { frontmatter: homepageSettings } }] }
  }
}) => {
  const wrapperClasses = classNames(
    'page-wrapper',
    {
      'page-wrapper--custom': location.pathname.split('/')[1]
    },
    `page-wrapper--${location.pathname.split('/')[1]}`
  );
  return (
    <div className={wrapperClasses}>
      <Helmet>
        <html lang="uk" />
      </Helmet>
      <Navbar location={location.pathname} className={location.pathname.split('/')[1]} {...navbarSettings} />
      <Feedback
        location={location}
        email={homepageSettings.contactFormEmail}
        title={homepageSettings.contactFormTitle}
      />
      {children()}
      <Subscribe email={homepageSettings.contactFormEmail} className={location.pathname.split('/')[1]} />
      <Footer {...footerData} {...navbarSettings} className={location.pathname.split('/')[1]} />
    </div>
  );
};

export const pageQuery = // very long query which appears to be sound
```

So, returning to my question:

**How do can I dynamically add or remove a class-name to `wrapperClasses` based on a state that I pass to the `<Feedback` component and where would I instantiate this state to reoad the entire page, when it changes.**

Thanks in advance folks.